# I have a big problem with provider and pageView and filtering the lists and validator in TextFormField

Tags: flutter, dart, oop, flutter-test, flutter-provider

I have two hours to deliver.
The problem is that I have an sign up page, which is originally a PageView that contains five pages.
The first page has an email field only.. Why? When he fills it in, I take the value and compare it if it already exists or not..
In case it is not exist, it will go to the second page, which is "Verify your account"
I will send him a code to enter. If it is correct, he will go to the third page to fill in his information in case he exits from the application and did not fill out the remaining information pages and try again to create an account, but this account has been verified, so I want him to skip the verify page and go to the data pages directly
How can I achieve this?
Here is my Model

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';
import 'package:uuid/uuid_util.dart';

class User {
  String userId = "";
  String userEmail = "";
  String userFirstName = "";
  String userLastName = "";
  String password = "";
  String userMobileNumber = "";
  int companyMobileNumber = 0;
  String companyPromotionName = "";
  String companyLocalName = "";
  int commercialRegNumber = 0;
  String companyEmail = "";
  File logoPhoto = File("");
  String address = "";
  String categories = "";
  bool isVirified = false;
  bool isNewUser = true;
  bool infoFilled = false;

  User.email(this.userEmail, this.userId, this.isVirified, this.infoFilled);

  User(
      {required this.companyEmail,
      required this.userFirstName,
      required this.userLastName,
      required this.password,
      required this.userMobileNumber,
      required this.companyMobileNumber,
      required this.companyPromotionName,
      required this.companyLocalName,
      required this.commercialRegNumber,
      required this.logoPhoto,
      required this.address,
      required this.categories});

  User.empty();
}

class Users with ChangeNotifier {
  List<User> users = [];
  Uuid uuid = Uuid(options: {'grng': UuidUtil.cryptoRNG});
  File? image;
  String emailAddress = "";
  bool isVirified = false;
  bool infoFilled = false;

  void addEmail() {
    //return true for new users
    users.add(User.email(emailAddress, uuid.v4(), isVirified, infoFilled));

  }



}
```

**TextFormField**
`      validator: (value) {
//Check if the value entered exist at Database  (down function)*************
final checkUser = users.every((user) => user.userEmail != value!.toLowerCase());

```
    if (value!.isEmpty) {
      return 'Email address is required';
    } else if (!isValid(value)) {
      return "Email address incorrect";
    } else if (checkUser) {
      return "Email address is exist, try Login ";
    }else {
      setState(() {
        context.read<Users>().emailAddress = value.toLowerCase().trim();
      });
    }
  },`
```

**Continue Button after entered email**

```
 TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            if (!EmailKeys.formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
              return;
            } else {
              print(context.read<Users>().users);
             final isVirified =context.read<Users>().users.firstWhere((user) =>
                      user.userEmail != context.read<Users>().emailAddress).isVirified;
             isVirified ? widget.pageController.jumpToPage(2)
                  : widget.pageController.nextPage(
                      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 50),
                      curve: Curves.easeOut,
                    );
            }
          },
```

**Screen Verification**

```
                    onCompleted: (v) {
                  formKey.currentState!.validate();
                  // conditions for validating
                  if (currentCode.length != 5 || currentCode != "55555") {
                    errorController.add(ErrorAnimationType
                        .shake); // Triggering error shake animation
                    setState(() {
                      hasError = true;
                    });
                  } else {
                    setState(() {
                      widget.currentIndex++;
                      context.read<Users>().isVirified=true;
                      context.read<Users>().addEmail();
                      hasError = false;
                      ScreenVerification.verificationEmail = true;
                      widget.pageController.nextPage(duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 10),curve: Curves.easeOut,);

                    });
                  }
                },
```

Comment: HELP! PLease!!!!

Comment: Basically, you want to check if a user verified or not at the initialization, correct?

Comment: Yes exactly!!!!

Comment: any Help guyys??